# Webpack: External modules and ES modules interoperability

Tags: webpack, react-redux, webpack-4

I've been searching the webs for an hour, hoping I'm not asking a duplicate question, but I don't find anything really on my issue, but it feels like this should happen to people other than me.

#### So here's the setup:

- We have a html file with 3 script tags (React, ReactDOM, and our application bundle)
- React and ReactDOM are loaded as UMD modules, with the "var" type, so they'll appear on window, like `window.React` and `window.ReactDOM`
- Our application bundle is bundled with webpack, has `externals` links to React and ReactDOM, and uses `react-redux`.

#### Now the problem is the following:

webpack bundles the es6 module compliant file from `react-redux` to our bundle (I never asked it to do so), which means, it'll import the file pointed at by the "module" field in `package.json` , and that uses ES6 type default import for React, like this in one of its files:

`import React from 'react';`

Because of the external module linking in webpack, this will virtually translate to this:

```
React = webpack_require('react').default 
// where webpack_require('react') will resolve to window.React
```

Unfortunately, the React UMD module that's loaded on the window doesn't expect to be consumed like this, it doesn't have a default export, so `react-redux` blows up.

#### Questions

To make this work, I have a few options, but couldn't quite achieve any of them. I think any of these would get me to the finish line.

How do I tell `webpack` to look at `react-redux` as a damn CJS/UMD module, and not an ES6 module... use the "main" field from the package.json, and not the "module"?

How do I tell `webpack` to artificially wrap up the external "React" to look like an ES6 module like this:

```
React = webpack_require('react').default
// and webpack_require('react') should resolve to {default: React}
```

Is there any other way out? Should I also make `react-redux` external then?

Comment: did you ever solve? Webpack and ES modules seem enemies in all the possible ways https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8895

Comment: No, didn't solve it in a nice way. For some reason, when the bundle is used in an AMD context, the importing works, but when used as a 'var' type module, it blows up.